# Adding channel entries to a specific group in Friends

Tags: solspace, solspace-friends

Is it possible to add channel entries to a group and let it respect the privacy settings of that group?

1. In other words: Allow the group creator to create content (channel entry) for a group.
2. If the group is private, then those channel entries respect that
3. If not private, then users can read/comment/interact with that channel entry.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## 1.

If you look at the example in the documentation (http://www.solspace.com/docs/friends/group_entry_add/#examples), you can see this dropdown to display groups when using the Group Entry Add form:

```
<select name="friends_group_id[]" multiple="multiple">
   {exp:friends:groups dynamic="off"}
       <option value="{friends_group_id}">{friends_group_title}</option>
   {/exp:friends:groups}
</select>
```

You could limit that list to group owners using the `{friends_group_owner_id}` parameter (http://www.solspace.com/docs/friends/groups/#friends_group_owner_id):

```
<select name="friends_group_id[]" multiple="multiple">
   {exp:friends:groups dynamic="off"}
      {if logged_in_member_id == friends_group_owner_id}       
          <option value="{friends_group_id}">{friends_group_title}</option>
      {/if}
   {/exp:friends:groups}
</select>
```

## 2.

The `private=""` parameter in {exp:friends:group_entries} should allow you to not show entries from a private group. In the docs: http://www.solspace.com/docs/friends/group_entries/#private

## 3.

See answer for #2. Commenting and interacting (I'm assuming editing?) with entries depends on the code you decide to put inside `{exp:friends:group_entries}`

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a shot. Might be a while but I will update this after I test the whole thing out. This could potentially be very powerful. Exciting.